# Writing multiples JS File with LUA Script? (Simultaneously)

Tags: javascript, lua

I can't seem to find the answer to the following question.

Can I open multiple file at once  with io.open() and stock these files in different local variables?

I will be reading one file and form that file generate various .js files which will be used has source for a project of mine.  I'm doing this to ease the maintenance of those sources files.

Comment: Yes you can certainly open multiple files at once with `io.open` (with the FDs in different variables.)  What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: I could not find the answers anywhere, probably because it's too easy lol.  I asked because I remember some language do not offer multiple files opened at the same time. 

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can open multiple file using `io.open`.

However, since Lua calls C's `fopen` to do the actual job, there is a limit of the maximum opened file numbers, it's guaranteed to be at least `FOPEN_MAX`. In practice, this is rarely a problem, so don't worry unless you really need to open many files.